# React LightBox (react-images): Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I get the error in the console "Cannot read property 'state' of undefined" when I try to run the below code. I believe it has to do with the use of `this.` but I don't know how to fix it. I'm using the quick start example from here: https://github.com/jossmac/react-images. Can anyone help?

```
 ReactDOM.render(

          <div>
           <Lightbox
            images={[{ src: 'http://example.com/img1.jpg' }, { src: 'http://example.com/img2.jpg' }]}
            isOpen={this.state.lightboxIsOpen}
            onClickPrev={this.gotoPrevious}
            onClickNext={this.gotoNext}
            onClose={this.closeLightbox}
          />



          </div>,
            document.getElementById("contents")
        )
```

Comment: the error is kinda self explanatory. Have you tried to put this jsx code into a react component and let it rendered using ReactDOM?

Comment: Change `this.state.lightboxIsOpen` to `true` and remove `onClickPrev`, `onClickNext`, and `onClose`. You aren't using those, so don't copy them from the example.

Comment: @Aaron Ah, I see. Another question, if I were to define lightboxIsOpen, gotoPrevious, gotoNext, closeLightbox, where do I define it?

Comment: @intangibles In a component, like their example, although in their example they don't show that part, they do use a component. You are using `ReadDOM.render()` so you don't really have anywhere to put it, at least in the React component tree. You could put it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a `React Component` and define all its properties. You can then render that component with `ReactDOM.render()` like

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      lightboxIsOpen: true
    }
    this.gotoPrevious = this.gotoPrevious.bind(this);
    this.gotoNext = this.gotoNext.bind(this);
    this.closeLightbox = this.closeLightbox.bind(this);
  }
  gotoPrevious() {
     //....body here
  }
  gotoNext() {
    //..body here
  }
  closeLightbox() {
    //..body here
  }
  render() {
    return (
       <div>
           <Lightbox
            images={[{ src: 'http://example.com/img1.jpg' }, { src: 'http://example.com/img2.jpg' }]}
            isOpen={this.state.lightboxIsOpen}
            onClickPrev={this.gotoPrevious}
            onClickNext={this.gotoNext}
            onClose={this.closeLightbox}
          />

      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
        <App/>,document.getElementById("contents")
        )
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I was able to understand where I should put the constructors and define the function. How do I render images as thumbnails from inside Lightbox? I'm calling this.renderGallery() in a div, but I don't know how to define the function to pull the image from Lightbox to display as thumbnail.